# Starting "Alert Me" automatically

Tags: 2013, alert

I've come across to programmatically assign list/library alerts to a single SharePoint user, is it possible to do the same but for more than just one user or maybe a SharePoint group?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can assign a workflow to do this when a document are created or edited. See:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nNxD82KiUhQ

You can format the email with the required information such as: Who edited, who created, when it was created, when it was edited and etc.